# need regex for youku video id

Tags: php, regex

Following are the possible inputs from users.

> `<embed src="http://player.youku.com/player.php/sid/XMTQxNzMxMjI0/v.swf" quality="high" width="480" height="400" align="middle" allowScriptAccess="sameDomain" allowFullscreen="true" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"></embed>`

> `http://player.youku.com/player.php/sid/XMTQxNzMxMjI0/v.swf`

> `http://v.youku.com/v_show/id_XMTQxNzMxMjI0.html`

I need a regular expression to extract video ID from the provided input.

Comment: Have you even tried creating a regular expression on your own?

Comment: yes many, but didnt work

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Give me the codez questions aren't welcome here, please read the FAQ. This site is about concrete problems you encountered while programming, not something that general as your question where it's obvious you didn't do anything to solve the programming problem in a useful manner.

Comment: @AtifAli what application language did you use the regular expression in?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

here's how i would do it. id in first capture group.

```
youku\.com/(?:player.php/sid/|v_show/id_)([a-zA-Z0-9]+)(?:/|\\.)
```

i understand now that you use php as application language, which changes things a bit. you have to start and end the regular expression with a formality character of your own choice. for this regular expression i'd use the hash character, since it's not used anywhere in the regular expression:

```
$regExp = "#youku\.com/(?:player.php/sid/|v_show/id_)([a-zA-Z0-9]+)(?:/|\\.)#";
```

Comment: Here are new formats introduced by youku ,

 http://v.youku.com/v_show/id_XMTYzOTc0NjA=.html

Can I have the updated regex plz 

http://static.youku.com/v1.0.0212/v/swf/loader.swf?VideoIDS=XMTYzOTc0NjA%3D&embedid=MTE1LjE4Ni45NC4xMjQCNDA5OTM2NQIC


http://player.youku.com/player.php/sid/XMTYzOTc0NjA=/v.swf

Comment: @AtifAli I have used this Reges but when I save the link it does not save and gives the error of `This value should not be null.`. I am using this into sonata bundle by making my own provider,

Answer (score 1):

Here is regex (the best I can give for the amount of details you provide, it includes a lot of guessing)

```
(?<=sid\/|\/id_)[^.\/]+
```

OK, I will give some more details than you did:

- See and test your regex [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2vm1e)
- Find more details and learn regular expressions here on [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)
  (Hint: I used a lookbehind assertion, an alternation, a negated character class and a quantifier)

Comment: Thanks , but cant get video id . 
Check this  $regExp = "(?<=sid\/|\/id_)[^.\/]+";
preg_match($regExp, $product_video, $match);
print_r($match);

Comment: @AtifAli The regex above doesn't include the `/` delimiters outside the regex. You'll have to add them. e.g., `$regExp = '/(?<=sid\/|\/id_)[^.\/]+/';`

Comment: @AtifAli note that the delimiters outside the regex doesn't have to be the forward slash. it could be any character, as long as it's the same one at the start and at the end.